# JMeter - Load Test - Webform multiple page

Tags: webforms

I need to load test a multiple page web form in a Drupal site; using jMeter. In the test plan, I have the following:

- HTTP Request Defaults
- HTTP Cookie Manager
- Thread Group

  - HTTP request (i.e. first page of the questionnaire). It includes Regular Expression Extractor to define the form_build_id
  - HTTP request (i.e. second page of the questionnaire).  It also includes Regular Expression Extractor to define the form_build_id

The test does not fail but no new submission get registered for the given form in Drupal.

Any idea how to load test a Drupal site with a multi page questionnaire using JMETER?